# create trigger in zabbix for constant value over the period

Tags: zabbix

I want to create trigger in zabbix which should get executed when the value for particular item is constant for the period of 5 min.
exa:- If value of item `x` is 20 and it remained as 20 for 5 min, then trigger should get executed. I don't want to use avg() function since it is uncertain for some of the situations. Does anyone has any idea how to create trigger for above?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `{host:item.min(5m)}={host:item.max(5m)}`.

Comment: I will try this solution

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

{Java CPU Utilization:item.min(10m)}>90

Here what will happen is when minimum value in last 10min is above 90 then it will trigger. It simply means value of item was constantly above 90 in last 10 min. 
I hope it serves your purpose.

Comment: This is completely unrelated to the question. The question was about a constant value, not about values being above a threshold.